# Joomla 3.4.3 get fatal error while opening plugins

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, administrator, controller, fatal-error

While trying to open any plugin from Joomla administration, a blank page with this error message displays:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on a non-object in .../libraries/legacy/controller/form.php on line 366
```

Can someone helps me to fix this please?

---

Yes, update J from 2.5.28 to 3.4 and then just installed and customized helix template.

Comment: Did you install anything or make any changes recently?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might end up here through a Google search, trying to find a solution to a similar problem:

Usually fatal errors especially after an update may mean that some files didn't copied over correctly. Reinstalling Joomla and extensions and update to latest version usually solves such issues.

In many cases I would recommend to perform a manual re-installation, by substituting Joomla core files with those taken from a fresh Joomla download.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the latest versions of third party extensions (e.g. the Gantry Framework if you are using this), clear the Joomla cache and try again.

Reference: http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/free-joomla-stuff/254180-solved-rockettheme-afterburner2-template-s-style

Answer (score 0):

Try to find and rename to anything (for example add "_") folder at /libraries/cms/controller